# Fire button click event using a key combination in c#

Tags: c#, button, user-controls, click, key

I've created custom button derived from a normal .Net button and have added the following property to add a short cut key combination:

```
public Keys ShortCutKey { get; set; }
```

I want this combination to fire the click event of the button but have no idea how to implement this when the button is placed on a form. I know the standard way of doing a button shortcut is to use the & before the short cut character but I need to use a key combination.

Any ideas?

Many Thanks

Comment: Have a look at input binding. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the form's ProcessCmdKey() method to detect shortcut keystrokes.  Like this:

```
    private bool findShortCut(Control.ControlCollection ctls, Keys keydata) {
        foreach (Control ctl in ctls) {
            var btn = ctl as MyButton;
            if (btn != null && btn.ShortCutKey == keydata) {
                btn.PerformClick();
                return true;
            }
            if (findShortCut(ctl.Controls, keydata)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (findShortCut(this.Controls, keyData)) return true;
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Where MyButton is assumed to be your custom button control class.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that but if I have loads of buttons & forms I have to do that for each one. I need to be able to just drop the button on the form and set the Short Cut Keys via the property panel. So I need all the code within my button class.

Comment: Iterate the controls to find your buttons back.  Post updated.

Comment: Great. I've used your suggestion. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using WinForms, given that the ampersand character is used in WinForms control captions to denote the shortcut character. If that is the case, then you can use the [`Button.PerformClick()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) method on a WinForms `Button` in order to fire the `Click` event manually.

If this is not the case and you are, in fact, using WPF; then take a look at the link [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572559/dmitry) has posted in his comment for [WPF Input Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am using WinForms. I still don't understand how the Button.PerformClick will be fired? I would have to write code on each form the button is on to capture the key combination. I want to be able to place my custom button on any form and have the developer set the key combination from the property window. Then I need that combination to fire the click event without have to add any code to the form. Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: @user1131661 From what I understand, you should be able to achieve that by listening for keyboard events inside your custom button implementation and then firing the `Click` event if the specified shortcut combination has been pressed. Note that in this case, you would be best storing the shortcut combination *inside* the custom button implementation and exposed through a property. Does that help at all?

Comment: Hi Samuel, Thanks for the reply. I've just tried that. I can only seem to capture the keyboard events when the button has focus. I've overridden the ProcessCmdKey & ProcessDialogKey to try getting this to work. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @user1131661 That is pretty much what I meant. However, those methods will only fire when the control is in focus. Because you need to listen to global key presses, you may be better off developing some means of listening to the keyboard, as opposed to key presses on the `Button`. Take a look at [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/winforms-accessing-mouse-and-keyboard-state) article for some idea of how you might go about doing this. Note that you may have to have some background thread running that has the sole purpose of checking the key state(s).