# Using ctrl+z keys to implement our own Undo method/function in WPF and disabling the default undo command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How to use ctrl+z (ApplicationCommand.Undo) key for implementing our own undo method, rather than using the default command in WPF. Basically replacing the default command with our own undo method.

for example: I want to bind ctrl+z command to my method: 
             **private void OnMenuItemUndo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)** in 
             xaml.cs file.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/8927120/2832222

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way in below.  It assumes that a data source object which exposes a `ICommand` type property named `YourUndoCmd` has already binded to one of `TextBox`'s ancester's `DataContext` property.

```
<TextBox IsUndoEnabled="false">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="Z" Command="{Binding YourUndoCmd}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>  
</TextBox>
```

### Update

The `CommandBinding` way.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Executed="Undo_ExeCuted" Command="ApplicationCommands.Undo"/>
    </Grid.CommandBindings>

    <!--TextBox that will use your undo logic.-->
    <TextBox IsUndoEnabled="False"/>

    <!--TextBox that will use build-in undo logic.-->
    <TextBox />
</Grid>
```

In your code-behind, there should be a method like below to handle the undo command.

```
private void Undo_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: So my method: `private void OnMenuItemUndo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` should be in `MyUndoCmd` class which inherits `ICommand`?

Comment: If you insist on handling 'Undo' in code-behind, you also can use a `CommandBinding` to redirect 'Undo' `RoutedUICommand` to a `ExecutedRoutedEventHandler` you specified. I will update my answer.

Comment: Your updated solution worked perfect! Thank you very much. :)